# Multi-peer connectivity in iOS

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I am new in Multi-peer connectivity API.

Is it possible to communication between PC or iMac to iPhone or iPad devices using Multi-peer connectivity API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Multipeer is not available for PC.

In iOS, the framework uses infrastructure Wi-Fi networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth personal area networks for the underlying transport.

In MacOS and tvOS, it uses infrastructure Wi-Fi, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Ethernet.

It might be possible to connect cross platform. Like macOS and iOS.

Check this [thread](https://9to5mac.com/2014/06/05/apple-brings-multipeer-connectivity-to-mac-enables-cross-platform-nearby-networking-w-ios/).

Comment: Thanks.I will check